# Boost shared memory. How many processes are currently using the shared memory?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, ipc, shared-memory

I am sharing some memory between processes, using the boost library;

boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory managed_shm(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, "shm", 1024);

is there a way to find out how many processes are currently accessing this memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the underlying SHM ID, you can use shmctl function to get the number of processes having the segment attached.

Comment: Sounds good, and works with regular memory sharing. But how can I get the underlying SHM ID when using boost?

Comment: There's a get_shmid method on the underlying xsi_shared_memory object. You should really read the docs.